# How to convert image to 3/sec video as mp4 in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

How to convert image to 3/sec as mp4 file video in flutter.

my question looks so simple , but i spent many days searching , cannot find way

Answer (score 0):

Your question looks really simple, but it isn't. A video file can be much more complicated than a simple Image. Flutter on its own can't do this. You would need to use an external encoder that creates the h264 video from your pixeldata.

I couldn't find a dart package that can do this so you would probably need to write some platform specific code using platform channels or wrap a library using dart FFI. Keep in mind that encoding a video file requires a lot of performance or a hardware encoder that differs on each platform. Since you didn't provide any information about your target platform or specific usecase there isn't much more I can help with.

The best approach is probably to look into FFMPEG and its CLI and look there for an encoder.

Comment: do you think the following plugin is suiting my case use ? i am really feeling lost . it looks large plugin .. https://pub.dev/packages/ffmpeg_kit_flutter

Comment: Since I don't know your use case or platform I don't know if it will work.

Comment: simply i want user to convert any image he picked from his gallery to any duration/sec video , and add text or overlay image on the video .. i want make sure that it is the right plugin for me before i waste time on studying it

Comment: if you have idea on it please help me with advises

Answer (score 0):

check this code take a list of image and a make video with your desired fps and save video to gallery just add this packages : https://pub.dev/packages/ffmpeg_kit_flutter ,

```
    Future<void> createVideoFromImages(List<Uint8List> images) async {
    final tempDir = await getTemporaryDirectory();
    final videoPath = '${tempDir.path}/output_${DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch}.mp4';

    final imagePaths = <String>[];

    for (int i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
      final imagePath = '${tempDir.path}/image$i.png';
      await File(imagePath).writeAsBytes(images[i]);
      imagePaths.add(imagePath);
    }

    final ffmpegCommand = [
      '-framerate', '8',
      '-i', '${tempDir.path}/image%d.png',
      '-c:v', 'libx264',
      '-pix_fmt', 'yuv420p',
      videoPath,
    ];

    final session = await FFmpegKit.executeWithArguments(ffmpegCommand);

    final logs = await session.getLogs(); // Get the logs

    for (final log in logs) {
      print(log.getMessage()); // Print each log message
    }

    if (ReturnCode.isSuccess(await session.getReturnCode())) {
      await GallerySaver.saveVideo(videoPath);
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
        const SnackBar(
          content: Text('Video saved to gallery'),
        ),
      );
    } else {
      print('Error: Video creation failed');
    }
  }
```